# How to use odbc to import excel file into mysql table via c++?

Tags: c++, mysql, excel, odbc

I have a c++ program, and I am planning to use odbc to communicate my c++ program with mysql tables.

There is alot of tutorials online on how to access mysql tables using c++ and odbc, but how do I use c++ and odbc to load a excel file into mysql tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to save the file as a CSV and then execute the following statement

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘C:\\temp\\yourfile.csv’ INTO 
TABLE database.table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘;’ 
ENCLOSED BY ‘”‘ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\r\n’ (field1, field2);
```

in your program. i.e. if you are using the C++ wrapper,

```
stmt = con->createStatement();
stmt->execute(<above statement>);
```

This should work.

If you are using the C APIs then use

```
mysql_query(conn,<above query>)
```

The other way to do this would be to connect to Excel via an ODBC connection, import the data from there and import into MySQL. This is more complicated.

Comment: thank you for your help, do you know any good websites to learn odbc for c++?

Comment: Your welcome. You can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867424/know-of-a-good-c-mysql-odbc-tutorial)

Comment: @Jan S do you know difference between excel and csv file. Then the question is about csv file.